# Как поменять inet addr (Ubuntu)?

Tags: ubuntu, сеть, ifconfig, ip-address

Добрый день!Подскажите, пожалуйста, как поменять адрес в Linux Ubuntu 13.10?Пытаюсь командой     `ifconfig eth0 192.168.123.15 netmask 255.255.255.0`

Но при вызове ifconfig данные остаются старые.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В терминале:

sudo service network-manager stop

sudo service networking stop

sudo ifconfig eth0 down

sudo ifconfig eth0 your_new_address

sudo ifconfig eth0 up

sudo service networking start

Как-то так ...

Comment: Да, достойно

Answer (score 1):

Вообще-то синтаксис правильный, правда, не помню точно, поддерживается ли он в linux. а посмотрите, не управляются ли ваши интерфейсы т.н. менеджером соединений (подобная штука точно есть в openSuse и при его работе ifconfig бессилен). Если действительно манагер есть и работает - отключите его. Да, ещё как вариант попробуйте перезапустить ифейс (ifconfig eth0 down && ifconfig eth0 up) ну или весь inetd

Comment: @danila, спасибо, а как посмотреть есть ли он?

Comment: Загляните в GUI-ифейс управления сетью, думаю, там будет. Убунты. к сожалению под рукой нет, линуксы юзаю последнее время редко. Окончательно ушёл на BSD несколько лет назад

Comment: Если есть менеджер соединений (а по-умолчанию в Убунту он ставится), то меняйте параметры в нем. Посмотрите - есть ли значек в трее. По ПКМ вызываете настройку.

Comment: @Ice_Fox, я бы порекомендовал добавить    # ifconfig eth0 down && ifconfig eth0 up---UP@danila, пардон, не дочитал до конца Ваш ответ...)